# How to pass values from DIalog class to it's host

Tags: java, android, dialog

So this is my Dialog class:

```
public class SecondActivity extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.second, null))
                .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

In my dialog there are 2 edit texts which get 2 strings. I want to use those 2 strings in my MainActivity if the user presses on the save button. How do I do that?

Comment: Use getActivity() what returns your host activity instance. Maybe ((MainActivity) getActivity ()).setString1("text") if you have a method setString1 (...) in MainActivity.

Comment: This might help: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents

Answer (score 0):

The inflate method returns a view where you can execute a findViewById, like the following:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second, null);
    EditView editView = (EditView)v.findById(R.id.your_edit_view);
    builder.setView(v)
            .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```